# XSRF-Token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, header, csrf

I implement login in laravel on login request there is two token generate one in body and another one is in header cookie.

When i remove value of body token it's show page expired error but when I remove value of xsrf-token it's not shows any error and login getting succesfull

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: <host>
Content-Length: 513
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: <Origin Address>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent:
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=<token>; laravel_session=<session token>
Connection: close

_token=<token>&userName=<userName>&password=<Password>
```

Anyone help me to explain this both token. and why page is not getting expired on remove value of xsrf-token value using burpusite tool.

Comment: Are you talking about the `csrf-token` as a `<meta>` element in the page `<head>`?

Comment: No i am talking about xsrf-token which is add in cookie in header at every request from my page

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf):

> Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site
> request forgery (CSRF) attacks. Cross-site request forgeries are a
> type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed
> on behalf of an authenticated user.

also:

> Laravel stores the current CSRF token in an encrypted XSRF-TOKEN
> cookie that is included with each response generated by the framework.
> You can use the cookie value to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header.
> This cookie is primarily sent as a convenience since some JavaScript frameworks and libraries, like Angular and Axios, automatically place its value in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header on same-origin requests.